# How can users ask private questions anonymously on this site?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, questions

Often the topics of questions may be very private, how would a user ask a question anonymously considering their profile is linked to their other profiles on the Stack Exchange network?

Comment: I agree, some sites (like this one or Workplace) would immensely benefit from the ability to post anonymously without making a second account.

Answer (score 10):

If you're afraid that your account may be traced back to you in real life, you could consider [making a second account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148915/369802):

> You will want to make sure your login credentials and contact emails are completely distinct, though, so that your accounts don't get merged automatically.

**Please, please make sure to register your second account as well, so you can respond to possible requests for clarifications in comments and so we can see that if you edit, it's the person that originally asked the questions that is editing it now**.

If you do make a second account, make sure there's absolutely NO interaction between your two accounts:

> So long as there's no voting or other dubious-looking stuff (like one account asking a question and another immediately answering it) going on between the accounts, it's really not a big deal.

This will make sure there's no way to trace back that you wrote the post, and you should be able to post very anonymously.

Comment: Once you get a good answer, you should also have the question dissociated from your account so that the question isn't attributed to your main account in case both are "accidentally" merged for some reason.

Comment: @gparyani You could request that (it's certainly not mandatory), but I haven't seen that recommended anywhere for throwaway accounts. In fact, the meta's on post dissociation state that CM's might request you to delete your account instead of having posts dissociated if you don't have much participation.

Comment: Technically, the CC BY-SA license means that the team is legally required to accept requests for dissociation; if they do make such a request, you can always cite the license and get them to follow through with it. I find it more convenient to request dissociation because you can then use the same alternative account in case you want to ask a different private question later.

Comment: These seem like hoops that have to be jumped through to achieve something that is perhaps quite a common need. TheStudentRoom just has a checkbox "post anonymously"...

Answer (score 8):

For this, You may create a new anonymous account which is not linked to any SE site. This way, your question can't be traced.

**However, remember** you shouldn't be using this account to interact with your original account in any manner.

From [this meta post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10159/499900) at Mathematics.SE,

> **Multiple accounts are usually tolerated, but they are not allowed to interact at all.** If you are e.g. just using a different account to ask a question anonymously, this is allowed as long as you don't vote on it, don't circumvent any rate limit on it and don't interact with that account in any other way.
>
> Interacting with your own accounts, and trying to give the impression that they belong to different users is not allowed.

From this [main meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/35607/321725),

> It is not a problem to have multiple accounts, as long as they aren't voting for each other and doing other sockpuppet-y things.

**In conclusion**, you can create another account and ask a question using that without breaking any rule.

Comment: It seems as though multiple accounts are not the best solution to this problem (even if the only solution, currently)

Comment: @EdmundReed I agree. I think this is a problem for Workplace.SE as well. I have been wanting to ask a question there but don't want my employer finding out. Perhaps a feature request should be made on Meta.SE (if it doesn't exist already).