# Can I ask a question here without it being linked to my main network account?

Tags: support, user-accounts

I'm tempted to ask a question on here but TBH, I don't want it to seen from any of my other SE accounts, especially SO. I do send my SO account to potential employers, etc and TBH, I don't want them to know about my personal/family problems. I appreciate that this site is in Beta and probably has limited controls but do you have any procedures around handling this situation?

Comment: What may help too: https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3139/1599

Comment: Being a developer that solution makes my palms sweat (hack...cough...hack) :) @Tinkeringbell. This and other recent controversies seems to point at this kind of thing not really being suited to the SO model. I guess that's a questions for SE(inc) when/if they graduate this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really.

There have been requests for private or anonymous question asking in the past.  The only way to do so is to log out and ask it without logging on, or to make a separate account for use only on this site.

You can [disconnect your account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/290092/172266), but this will only protect you against the most cursory overview.  It is still possible to trace the question back to the same set of accounts; it's just slightly harder.  Relevant questions on meta are tagged <kbd>[hidden-communities](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hidden-communities)</kbd>.

See in particular these posts on Meta Stack Exchange: [Need to ask a question anonymously](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/89248/172266) and *[Fix the misleading description of the "Hide Communities" feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/260138/172266)*

Comment: Hey Gerrit! :) thanks for the response. This essentially means I won't be participating in this community in any meaningful way then...